# ScriptingBridge: Are These Leaks Mine or Scripting Bridge?

Tags: cocoa

I converted my app from using Garbage Collection to ARC. The app uses the ScriptingBridge framework. Out of curiosity I ran it with Instruments "Leaks" template and there are leaks. The AEDescImpl objects are not created directly by my code, these seem to be created by Scripting Bridge. Am I right?

If these leaks are from ScriptingBridge, is this normal and I just have to live with it?

Thanks.

Here is an Instruments image that shows "Cycles & Roots" -> "Leak Cycles":

[image]

I typed in the relevant section.
_NSCFArray

```
    +40 ( no ivar ]: AEDescImpl
```

```
      +56 [ no ivar ]: AEDescImpl
```

```
      +64 [ no ivar ]: AEDescImpl
```

```
      +72 [ no ivar ]: AEDescImpl
```

```
      +80 [ no ivar ]: AEDescImpl
```

```
      +88 [ no ivar ]: AEDescImpl
```

```
      +96 [ no ivar ]: AEDescImpl
```

---

Peter's comment about including the method findOpenTuner in its entirety spurred me to create a "mini" project. The method in question was large and had many methods calls so I reduced the method down to its essence. I added a for loop to call the method 24 times as it ran so fast Instruments did not have any chance to see anything.

Out of curiosity, I commented out the for loop on EyeTVPlayer_window and ran Instruments on that and found no leaks or cycles. With this for loop uncommented as seen below, the leaks are present. It seems to me that either my coding is not correct or Scripting Bridge is leaking.

The "mini" project's implementation file.

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "EyeTV.h"

@implementation AppDelegate

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
    NSUInteger i;
    for (i=0; i<25; i++) {
        NSLog(@"before i=%li", i);
        [self findOpenTuner];
        NSLog(@"after i=%li", i);
    }
}

- (void)findOpenTuner;
{
    EyeTVApplication *eyeTVApp;

    eyeTVApp = [SBApplication applicationWithBundleIdentifier:@"com.elgato.eyetv"]; // 08-04-2011 needed to do mute below in method call filterPlayVolumeMute

    SBElementArray *eyeWindows = [eyeTVApp player_windows]; // are EyeTVWindow

    BOOL openTunerFound = FALSE;    // 07-21-2010
    int j=0;
    for (EyeTVPlayer_window *eyeWin in eyeWindows)  // 12-07-2012 #1
    {
        if ([[eyeWin programInfo] count] == 0) {
        } else {
            // this is the tuner we want
            openTunerFound = FALSE; // 07-21-2010
            [eyeWin select];    // 07-21-2010 // moves "focus" to window, places it at index 0
            break;              // 07-21-2010 // got the tuner, leave loop
        }
        j++;
    }
}

@end
```

Instruments screenshots of "mini" project.

[image]
[image]

Comment: You can see where the object was created in the Extended Detail pane along the right side. But don't just look at the AEDescImpl objects; where was the array created?

Comment: When I click on my method in the Extended details pane in Instruments, the code that is highlighted in red (with the "i" and 100%) is a method called findOpenTuners. An SBElementArray (NSMutableArray subclass) is being created in findOpenTuners -- this is the only spot where I'm creating an array.

Comment: Is `findOpenTuners` one of your methods? If so, please edit your question to include its entire implementation.

Comment: Also, I was originally asking where the arrays shown in the screenshot are created. Do any of their originating call stacks include any of your code?

Comment: I edited the question as Peter suggested and added some new detail.

Answer (score 0):

Same problem with ScriptingBridge. I ended up enclosing the responsible code with an autorelease pool.

```
@autoreleasepool {
  // Leaking code
}
```

That eliminated the biggest leaks and now it's only leaking a few bytes on my app.